# Sencha touch, fieldset onChange Listener

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I just want to `console.log('some info')` everytime when user selects an option on the fieldset, I tried this doesn't work for me.

```
                    {
                    xtype: 'fieldset', 
                    items: [{
                            id: 'selVehiclename',
                            xtype: 'selectfield', 
                            store:'itemvehicles',
                            valueField:'itemID',       
                            displayField: 'name'                                 
                            }],
                    listeners:{
                         change: function(slider, thumb, obj1, val) 
                         {
                             console.log('some info');
                         }
                    }
                },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Change` listener for `fieldset`.You should listen to `change` event inside the `selectfield`

```
{
                    xtype: 'fieldset', 
                    items: [{
                            id: 'selVehiclename',
                            xtype: 'selectfield', 
                            store:'itemvehicles',
                            valueField:'itemID',       
                            displayField: 'name',
 listeners:{
                         change: function(slider, thumb, obj1, val) 
                         {
                             console.log('some info');
                         }
                    }                                 
                            }],

                },
```